# simple function producing TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

This is really simple and I can't figure it out. Here's the code:

```
def combine(h0, gyro, vx, bias, len=400.0):
    for i in range(len(gyro)):
        print i

a = combine(3.0, [0.1, 0.2,0.3], [0.1, 0.2,0.3], 0.1)
```

This gives me an error:

```
 File "indoor.py", line 84, in 
   a = combine(3.0, [0.1, 0.2,0.3], [0.1, 0.2,0.3], 0.1)
 File "indoor.py", line 28, in combine
   for i in range(len(gyro)):
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I'm guessing it's going to be something really simple, but I just can't see the error!

Comment: In general don't use builtin names as your own variable names.. try something like `len_` instead of `len`.  The trailing-underscore convention seems to be recommended by the Python community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have assigned  len to a float `len=400.0`, so `len` no longer refers to the python function, just rename the parameter.

```
def combine(h0, gyro, vx, bias, ln=400.0):
    for i in range(len(gyro)):
        print i
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: No worries, might be time for a break ;)

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `__builtins__.len` to access the shadowed function, if you *really* like using `len` as the parameter name.